# HTTP Post Request in Objective-C Not Working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, post, parameters, http-post

I am writing an HTTP Post request, but for some reason the parameters are not being added correctly, and I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here's what I have:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:30];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";

// set Content-Type in HTTP header
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"text; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

// post body
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

// Dictionary that holds post parameters. 
NSMutableDictionary* _params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[_params setObject:subject forKey:@"subject"];
[_params setObject:message forKey:@"message"];
[_params setObject:[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName] forKey:@"device"];

// add params 
for (NSString *param in _params) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [_params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

// the server url
NSURL* requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:CIVCManifest.contactFeed];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// set the content-length
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

// set URL
[request setURL:requestURL];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

The request is getting through, however all the parameters are not being added properly. I had a Post script working that would upload a photo, and I copied and pasted most of it over to this one, but somehow this one is not working. Hopefully it's just a simple error I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 NSString *Post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Post Parameters"];
    NSURL *Url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Url"];

    NSData *PostData = [Post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [PostData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *Request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [Request setURL:Url];
    [Request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [Request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [Request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [Request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [Request setHTTPBody:PostData];
```

Comment: What happens to `meeting_Post`? I don't see it used anywhere after the declaration. And is the format of the parameters `"param1=value&param2=value2..."?

Comment: Ah, thanks for the edit. It works perfectly, I didn't realize it could be done so simply!

Comment: NSString *Post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"param1=%@&param2=%@",value1,value2];

Comment: @iAppDeveloper I have a Image stored in a UIImage. DO you know how to attach that to the POST request??