# Posting to the webserver the data in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, nsurlconnection

I searched  but I can't solve my problem .Here i want post the data to server. I have one user default, textview and textfield. please help out from this.

```
 NSUserDefaults *getting= [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] ;
 userID1=[getting   objectForKey:@"uId"];

 NSString *bodyString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"userId=%@&question=%@&categoryId=%@",userID1,askTextViewObj.text,specialistField.text];

 [bodyString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 NSLog(@"%@",bodyString);

request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" ] cachePolicy:0 timeoutInterval:30];                 
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPBody:[bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];
[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [bodyString length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-Length"];
connection=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self ];
if (!connection)
{
    UIAlertView* aler = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Network Error" message:@"Failed to Connect Server " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [aler show];

}

else
{
    NSLog(@"Connection is Successfully");

}
```

Comment: Doesn't `[bodyString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding...]` `return` something important?

Comment: Server Can't receiving the data

Comment: Your brain can't receiving the data.  That method returns something you want to save, not discard.

Comment: Try this And
[HTTP Post method]
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480689/http-post-request-in-objective-c-not-working/18480783#18480783

Comment: send me your id i will send demo code.,

Comment: @BhaveshNai My mail id pandu.3489@gmail.com

Comment: @user2695204 i send it.........